# How can I use a variable to set the value on a data attribute in query

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I have the following line of code that I am trying to set the value on:

```
var imgCount = $('.ito-image-wrap').length;
$('#load-super-hero').data('placement')=== imgCount;
```

The variable value is not working. How should write this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Are you trying to _set_ a data-attribute value?

Comment: Yes I am trying to set the data attribute value

Comment: Well then all you need is RTFM: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#load-super-hero').data('placement', imgCount);
```

JQuery uses a system of get/set inside the same function. Most of its functions called with one parameter are get methods, with two parameters they becomes a set method.

IT works also on other methods like attr, css, and so on, just look at the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

```
$('#load-super-hero').data('placement', imgCount);
```

**Please note that if you inspect the markup you may not see the attribute `data-placement`; however the data is cached and can be accessed using**:

```
$('#load-super-hero').data('placement');
```

To remove the data from the attribute you use:

```
$('#load-super-hero').removeData('placement');
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

```
var imgCount = $('.ito-image-wrap').length;
$('#load-super-hero').attr('data-placement', imgCount)
```